# Android: How to use audiotrack to make metronome?

Tags: android

I'm sort of a n00b with android's audiotrack class (I've just started to look over it, but I'm pretty sure I've got a good grasp on it), and I'm trying to make a metronome.

My idea is to just write into the audio sample with any data that will make a noise at certain intervals, and then write into the audio sample with 0's as data (no noise). Before I was using a timer, and using a formula (which outputs the interval in milliseconds) I came up with the set the interval, but the timer lags at certain points, which cannot happen.

So my question is how can I figure out how to write to the audio sample in correct intervals based on my formula? Or if this is a bad idea in your eyes, please tell why and, if you can, provide a different way to make the metronome along with some helpful websites/guides. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you have to understand the theory of sound and how it looks in waves.  A metronome is usually generates a wave similar to a sin wave.  If you look at this post, it explains everything from generating a sin wave and generating a sound from it.  It has a complete android project that works really well and is well documented.

Link to tutorial and understanding ->[Masters Touch](http://masterex.github.io/archive/2012/05/28/android-audio-synthesis.html)